# How to fix disk that is likely to fail soon?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Can I repair my hard disk?

[image]

I am a beginner with Ubuntu and I don't know how I can fix my hard drive or if it can be repaired.

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/386987/difference-between-smart-reallocated-sectors-and-bad-sectors and http://superuser.com/questions/26842/can-i-trust-a-hard-drive-that-has-had-to-reallocate-sectors - if it were only for this single reallocated sector I would not worry much but you also had **a lot** of read errors. This should not be on a 7 months old drive - RMA it if possible, or replace it soon.

Answer (score 2):

No way. SMART is a hardware test. And Reallocated Sectors is one of the important. If the value is actually increasing, find a replacement disk now and leave this one for nonimportant data.
However, I have an HDD which has this parameter bad for years already, but the number of bad sectors is not increaing.