# Periodic black screen with blk_update_request error

Tags: 16.04, dell

I have a Dell XPS (9360) running Ubuntu 16.04. About a year ago, it started black screening periodically and showing:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 116437120
EXT4-fs error (device sda3): ext4_find_entry:1456: inode #340837
EXT4-fs error (sda3): previous I/O error to superblock detected
```

[image: black screen boot messages]

Often, I will be using Chrome and a page will fail to load, then the entire OS freezes,then I have to hold down the power button to get it to restart.

UPDATE:
[image: SMART Data Window]

UPDATE 2:
All MemTest tests passed

BIOS version is now 2.13.0

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-version
Not Specified
```

UPDATE 3:

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Dec 17 18:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Jun 24  2016 ..
```

```
$ grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 20:23:06 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [17269.905713] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 20:23:06 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [17269.906533] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 20:23:06 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [17271.119478] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:28:00 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [19082.591888] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:28:00 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [19082.592009] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:28:00 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [19083.758325] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[712]: /dev/sda1: 42 files, 17939/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467358] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467557] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467561] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467686] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.471390]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.472370] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.458729] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.707539] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.636790] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog:Jan 19 21:59:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[966]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 10:45:26 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 4311.910055] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 10:45:26 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 4311.911213] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 10:45:26 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 4313.075318] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:10:20 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8976.540480] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:10:20 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8976.541865] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:10:20 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8977.733918] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[707]: /dev/sda1: 42 files, 17939/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481065] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481468] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481471] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481630] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.485371]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.486457] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.188938] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.428061] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.352099] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 14:28:19 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[941]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 18:25:08 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 6812.100654] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 18:25:08 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 6812.100707] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 20 18:25:08 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 6814.500147] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 22 22:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8821.672738] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Jan 22 22:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8821.672787] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Jan 22 22:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8822.867199] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[714]: /dev/sda1: 41 files, 15244/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.480605] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481103] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481106] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.481260] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.484990]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.486179] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.368862] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.616118] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.547363] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 12:20:24 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[740]: /dev/sda1: 41 files, 15244/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.489803] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.490327] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.490330] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.490488] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.494418]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.495444] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.308101] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.548909] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.469791] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:01:05 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[955]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[682]: /dev/sda1: 41 files, 15244/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.503977] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.504398] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.504401] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.504519] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.507760]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.508700] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.078704] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.342872] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.297129] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:34 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:35 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:35 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:35 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:35 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 13:02:35 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[937]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[731]: /dev/sda1: 41 files, 15244/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.466876] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467140] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467143] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.467261] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.470763]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.471792] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.041402] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.286870] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.234709] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:45 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:13:46 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[943]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[701]: /dev/sda1: 42 files, 17939/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.449278] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.449734] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.449736] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.449866] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.452992]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.453859] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.271545] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.547507] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.460352] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 15:45:03 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[945]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 systemd-fsck[720]: /dev/sda1: 42 files, 17939/126976 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.485860] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.486107] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.486109] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.486235] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.489568]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    1.490598] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.180609] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    3.434134] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [    4.328106] Adding 16534524k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16534524k SSFS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Current_Pending_Sector count - no Attribute 197
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 16:14:52 ann-XPS-13-9360 smartd[981]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.LITEON_CV3_8D128_11_SATA_128GB-TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 18:54:12 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 5714.825248] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 18:54:12 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 5714.825370] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 18:54:12 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 5716.246430] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 19:53:38 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8123.605275] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 19:53:38 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8123.607125] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 18 19:53:38 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 8124.820856] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 19 11:44:04 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [10280.840305] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 19 11:44:04 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [10280.840512] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 19 11:44:04 ann-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [10282.042380] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my disk dead? I cannot boot!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077933/is-my-disk-dead-i-cannot-boot)

Comment: @TejasLotlikar This question is not a duplicate of the question that you linked to because the `blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda` message printed in the black screen in this question is a specific device error message, it's not generic.

Comment: In order to give a proper recommendation, I need to see screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data window. Is this a HDD or SSD? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema updated

Comment: @Ann Thanks for the update. Did you run the `fsck`? If so, did it fix any problems? Is your disk a HDD or SSD? Can you backup important files before we bad block the device (assuming HDD)?

Comment: @heynnema I ran the `fsck`. It found
`Inode 1967643 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter` and I fixed.

Comment: The device is an SSD

Comment: @Ann Thanks for the update. Is your computer running any better/different after the fsck? Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema the computer is running differently. Now, it's no longer Chrome crashing, the entire OS freezes and requires a force restart. I will run the memory test and update the post with results.

Comment: @Ann Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and give my your exact model #.

Comment: @Ann Your BIOS should be 2.13.0 released 1/14/2020, as per https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-13-9360-laptop/drivers

Comment: @heynnema I just updated the BIOS version. I'm not sure how to get the exact model number.

Comment: @Ann Good job on the BIOS update. You typed an incorrect dmidecode command, and that's why you didn't get any answer. No mind. If you type the correct command, it should return 2.13.0 now. Have you run the memory test yet?

Comment: @heynnema yes, as posted in the update, I ran the memory test which passed

Comment: @Ann Good job on the memtest. I missed that update. All we have to do is see if your system runs better, without crashing/freezing/etc. Please keep me posted. If your system runs ok now, please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema I now seem to be getting occasional kernel panic manifesting as sudden black screen and blinking caps lock key. I have not found any clues in logs using `journalctl`.

Comment: @Ann please edit your question with the output of `ls -al /var/crash`, and also `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. The last one may be rather large, so you may have to copy/paste it at paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL.

Comment: @Ann Did your Dell come with SSD, or did you upgrade a HDD to SSD? Is the computer still under warranty?

Comment: @heynnema question updated. The Dell came with an SSD. It is no longer under warranty.

Comment: @Ann Thanks for the updates. Everything looks like a typical HDD/SSD problem, except the SMART Data looks good, and the syslog looks good. /var/crash was empty. You started with freezes, and it sounds like its gotten worse. In a last desperate test, try running off of a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if you freeze... if you do, then you may have a hardware problem. If you don't, then it's a Ubuntu problem, and at this point we would probably reinstall. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I've tried running Ubuntu from USB and haven't seen a freeze yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSD may be failing... or just in need to some good (over due) maintenance.

First, we need to check your filesystem, as you have inode errors, and then some...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #2:**

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

Your BIOS should be version 2.13.0, released on 1/14/2020, as per https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-13-9360-laptop/drivers

**Update #3:**

You need to update your SSD firmware. I think this will fix it.

```
LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB, S/N:TW0WVD60LOH006BP051C, WWN:5-002303-100c7f300, FW:T87110D, 128 GB
```

Go [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=fcx34&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-13-9360-laptop) to get the latest version...

```
Fixes & Enhancements
Fixes:
- Fix the system hang and disc detection issue due to FW bugs on certain corner cases

Enhancement:
- Improve the power consumption during idle state
Version
Version TCX110D, T8X110D
Category
Serial ATA
Release date
15 Jun 2017
Last Updated
03 Jan 2018
```

Comment: the provided update is only for Windows machines

Comment: @Ann this sounds like an important update. Many machines allow updating directly from the current BIOS without the need for Windows... check your User Manual, contact Dell, or try doing it this way... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A

Comment: According to Dell documentation, the update is supported only for "XPS models running the following Windows operating systems: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10". I was unable to update directly from the current BIOS without Windows.

Comment: @Ann Dell says it's only supported on Windows, because their .exe file only runs on Windows. Did you watch the video at the link that I gave you. It shows how it might be done without having Windows installed.

Comment: Yes, I saw the video. Booting DOS consistently fails.

Comment: @Ann Then you'll need to temporarily install Windows along side of Ubuntu, or take out the drive and connect it to a Windows computer. You may need the help of a technician.